# MySQL search all fileds with codeIgniter active query or alt. escaping (like + equals)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Logged in `$Account = 2; $SearchString = "Sally Do";`

```
$search_array = explode(' ',$SearchString);
```

People table example:

```
ID | Account | FirstName | LastName | Misc Other
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | John      | Doe      | Testing
2  | 2       | John      | Doe      | Pick Me
3  | 2       | Jonh      | Bob      | Not Me
```

If possible I would like to search all table fields without the need to specify them and to escape the values for the `LIKE` or preferably using CodeIgniter's Active Query.

```
SELECT * FROM poeple WHERE Account = 2 AND 
(

PHP 

foreach $search_array 
{
    FirstName LIKE '%svalue%' OR LastName LIKE '%svalue%'
}

)
```

Escaping breaks the SQL query and I'm sure I'm probably just doing something wrong...

```
$this->db->escape($search_array[0]);
$this->db->escape($search_array[1]);
```

I would much prefer a pure active query but I'm not sure it's possible?

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('people')->where('Account', $Account)->like(???)->get();
```

The issue mostly with active query is the lack of ( ) support so the Account doesn't become an `OR`.

**Decided to use an existing escaping function (built into CI) to use with a non-Active Query**

```
function escape_string($str, $like = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($str)){
        foreach ($str as $key => $val){
            $str[$key] = escape_string($val, $like);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    if ($like === TRUE){
        $str = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\\_'), $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('people');
$this->db->where('acount',$account);
if($first_name!='')
{
   $this->db->like('first_name',$first_name);
}
if($last_name!='')
{
   $this->db->like('last_name',$last_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$where = "(firstname LIKE '%".$value."%' OR lastname  LIKE '%".$value."%')";
$this->db->SELECT('*');
$this->db->from('people');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->where('account', $account);
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: the value wouldn't be escaped though